# Verb for denoting location

Tags: verb, verb-choice, verb-usage

I have noticed in German *sein* is not used as frequently as "to be" in English to denote where something is.

> The store is on the corner
>
> Your poster is on the wall
>
> Where is the closest restroom?

I mostly get *stehen/sein/sich befinden*/etc compared to *hängen* and *liegen*.

> Das Papier liegt auf dem Tisch (not *ist*)
>
> Das Bild hängt an der Wand (not *ist*)

But I don't really get when you would use *stehen, sein* and *sich befinden* (or any other similar verb) to say where something is (the parenthetical text is my guess)

> Where is the closet ATM? (*Wo befindet sich der nächste Geldautomat?*)
>
> The store is on the corner (*Der Laden steht an der Ecke*)
>
> The door is behind you (*Die Tür ist hinter dir*)

I don't really grasp if there is a difference and if so what it is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While **sein** is the most generally applicable way to denote the location of anything, it is indeed quite common in German to be more precise if possible.

**Befinden** is not more specific than **sein** when referring to locations, but it is a higher register in terms of formality.

Which more specific verb you can use depends a lot less on the kind of object you are referring to than on the position it is in (rule of thumb, there are exceptions):

**Stehen** (to stand):

1. applies to objects resting on a roughly flat surface if their height measured perpendicularly from that surface is significant relative to its other dimensions.
   It applies to towers (and buildings in general), trees, flowers in a vase, furniture in a room, **"Ein Buch steht im Regal"** but **"Ein Buch liegt auf dem Tisch"** etc.
2. to indicate that something is oriented the way it is supposed to, independently of its shape (most specifically when it is resting on some kind of legs or wheels): a bed **steht** somewhere, even if it is not very high, glasses on tables (unless they have toppled over), plates on tables (unless they are upside down), pans and pots on the oven etc.
3. to indicate that some vehicle is currenly immobile (a car in a garage, a train in a station) **but** ships are an exception, they **liegen** im Wasser/Hafen/vor Anker etc.

**Liegen** (to lie) applies to flat or elongated objects resting on a roughly flat surface if their elevation above that plain is insignificant: paper (and pens) on a desk, cutlery on a table, [an estate/a village/a city] in a landscape, etc.

**Hängen** (to hang) is used if an object is either fixed to a vertical wall or suspended from above: A picture or a mirror on the wall, a towel on a hook etc.

Comment: Nice definition of "stehen", but it totally fails with "Bett" and "Tisch" and "Couch" , "Pfanne" (steht auf dem Herd), "Teller" (steht auf dem Tisch)... there are many things that are not as high as they are wide or long and they still stehen.

Comment: Well, as always with such rules of thumb, the boundaries are blurry - what is considered insignificant varies. I'll edit a bit to highlight exceptions.

Comment: yes, that covers all the important ones I'd say :)

Comment: @Hulk: Great, very helpful answer!

Comment: ‘common in German to be more precise if possible’ — there’s the engineer coming through again xD

Answer (score 10):

Good news: you can use "sein" in all of this cases, especially when talking, and even more so as a foreigner. It is just an issue of style in written language to avoid these weak verbs ("sein", "haben") and use more specialized ones.

I have just a small problem with your choice "der Laden steht an der Ecke" (also confirmed by @hellcode). While I had no problem to use "steht" if there would be "das Haus" (the house, i. e. something touchable), using the function like "shop"  appears a bit strange and "befindet sich" would be my first choice. For more flat things like the paper on the table, a plot of land or a meadow "liegen" would be more appropriate due to the horizontal orientation.

Comment: Well, "der Laden steht an der Ecke" seems perfectly fine to me, but exclusively evokes the picture of a store occupying a building of its own (e.g. one of the typical free-standing Aldi/Lidl/... supermarkets), not a store integrated into a larger building.

Answer (score 1):

In these cases "sein" and "sich befinden" are used to describe or ask where something is. Then you can use both words with the same meaning. "Stehen" is similar to "liegen" and "hängen". It doesn't fit to everything. You cannot say "Die Tür steht hinter dir" (unless the door is hanged out of the anchors and it just lean against the wall). But to complicate it a bit, you can say "Die Tür steht offen", but this is just because the verb is "offen stehen".

Here are my proposed translations:

> Where is the closet ATM?
>
> Wo befindet sich der nächste Geldautomat?
>
> Wo ist der nächste Geldautomat?
>
> Wo finde ich den nächsten Geldautomaten?
>
> The store is on the corner.
>
> Der Laden befindet sich im Eckhaus.
>
> Der Laden steht an der Ecke.
>
> The door is behind you.
>
> Die Tür ist hinter dir.
>
> Die Tür befindet sich hinter dir.

Comment: I would not use **stehen** with **Laden** - this sounds strange to me. **Stehen** can be used for buildings, but a shop is usually only part of a building. Similarly, **stehen** is not used for appartments.

Comment: "Laden" could also be a kiosk. Then "stehen" is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Geographically, a location word that is often used is **liegt** (liegen). It means "lies" rather than "is"

> "Kalkutta liegt am Ganges, Paris liegt an der Seine..."

If the location is unknown (originally), befinden sich (a form of "finden") is sometimes used.

> Wo befindet sich eine Bank?